# What is session ID and how to get it in django?

Tags: django, django-sessions

What is the exact use of session ID, is it system generated or we assign it as we assign other dictionary values of session ? Please explain in layman terms.

Comment: why you need this? what is your presuppose? I'm asking because for example if you want to log in a user in Django via another app, you need to work with cookie, other programming languages for example ASP you just need the session

Comment: I was asked in an interview that what is session id, and where is it saved .

Comment: So, your question about session ID is in a general way :)

Comment: It was for django developer position, and asked about sessions in django.

Answer (score 3):

The [Django Session Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/) give a good explanation as well as providing great examples. Give that a read and you should have a good idea about how you can use sessions with Django.

Essentially it gives a good way to associate data with anonymous users, for example I just built a site where users add items to their cart and purchase the items. To be able to do that without requiring them to sign up for an account, I used session data.

Here are some [Example Code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/#examples) of how to use session data.

Comment: I understand that Django's session data is tied to browsers. But how does it differentiate one user from another - given that browser agents can be similar across a userbase.

Comment: @HassanBaig It puts a cookie on their individual browser.

Comment: @dfrankow: okay, I thought this was a pure server-side solution. Hence my question.

Comment: I see. It's not. The server puts a cookie on the browser. It also stores a bunch of session data on the server side, identified by the id in the browser cookie. So, most data is on the server, but there is some on the browser (client).